# How to check some value on every call to object's methods?

Tags: perl, oop, methods

I'd like to check on every call to my object's methods some value (in this case: token's age). Is it possible to set it to all methods at once? Like in constructor? I have such simple constructor:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args = @_;
    my $self  = {};

    $self->{key} = $args{key};
    bless($self, $class);

    ($self->{token}, $self->{token_start}) = $self->_get_authorized_token(); 
    return $self;
}
```

And bunch of methods, which depends of tokens age, like this:

```
sub add_item {
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = @_;
    ...
}
```

I'd like to avoid including age-checking in every method, so i look for more general way to implement it. Has there some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I can think of is to hide all your 'real' methods - either in the classical way with a preceding underscore, or in a hash of subroutines - and use `AUTOLOAD` to direct the call properly.

The example below shos the idea

**module** MyClass.pm

```
package MyClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
  bless {}, __PACKAGE__;
}

sub _method1 {
  print "In method1\n";
}

sub _method2 {
  print "In method2\n";
}

sub AUTOLOAD {

  our $AUTOLOAD;

  my ($class, $method) = $AUTOLOAD =~ /(.+)::(.+)/;
  return if $method eq 'DESTROY';

  my $newmethod = "${class}::_$method";
  unless (exists &$newmethod) {
    die qq(Can't locate object method "$method" via package "$class");
  }

  print "Preprocessing...\n";
  goto &$newmethod 
}

1;
```

**program**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyClass;

my $thing = MyClass->new;

$thing->method1;
$thing->method2;
$thing->method3;
```

**output**

```
Preprocessing...
In method1
Preprocessing...
In method2
Can't locate object method "method3" via package "MyClass" at MyClass.pm line 23.
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`Class::Method::Modifiers`](http://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aModifiers) or [`Class::Method::Modifiers::Fast`](http://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aModifiers%3a%3aFast) module.

Comment: Thank you for the right path - method modifiers! I didn't even know, what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think that if you're doing OO in Perl and you want to deal with things like attributes, method modifiers and deferred resource loading without the boilerplate, it's worth investing in learning [Moose](http://metacpan.org/module/Moose). To illustrate, this is one way to write what you want using Moose:

```
use Moose;
has key => (isa => 'Str', is => 'ro');
has token => (isa => 'HashRef', is => 'ro', lazy_build => 1);

before [qw(add_item method2 method3)] => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    if (do something with $self->token) {
         # return, die, etc.
    }
};

sub _build_token {
    my $self = shift;
    my $key = $self->key;
    return { token => 'foo', token_start => time };
}
```

These might be helpful:

- [Moose::Manual::MethodModifiers](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aMethodModifiers)
- [Moose::Cookbook::Basics::BinaryTree_BuilderAndLazyBuild](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aCookbook%3a%3aBasics%3a%3aBinaryTree_BuilderAndLazyBuild)